# Angular using anonymous function

Tags: angularjs, controller, anonymous-function

I need to display a table with two columns in a dashboard using a directive that call a controller using anonymous function and I am receiving errors inside the angular.js module:

index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="TableView.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="myNgApp">
        <div >
            <hpdTable></hpdTable>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

TableView.js page

```
angular.module('myNgApp').directive('hpdTable', TableView);

function TableView(){

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: function ($scope){
                $scope.names = [
                                    {
                                    "Name": "Security",
                                    "Number": "546543254"
                                    },
                                    {
                                    "Name": "System",
                                    "Number": "123456789"
                                    },
                                    {
                                    "Name": "Cloud",
                                    "Number": "9876564321"
                                    }
                                ];
            },
            templateUrl: 'TableView.html'
  };
}
```

TableView.html page

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="n in names">
    <td>{{ n.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ n.Number }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Use `<hpd-table></hpd-table>` instead.

Comment: Thanks dipseh but I am still receiving an error 

Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/nomod?p0=myNgApp(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:2005b @ angular.js:1929(anonymous function) @ angular.js:2003(anonymous function) @ TableView.js:1
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myNgApp&p1=Error%3A…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)

Comment: Can you please, make a plnkr with your code? It help to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 2):

If your directive is called "hpdTable", in your html tag you should use:

```
<hpd-table></hpd-table>
```

The camel-case name of the directive is always separed with "-" in the html tag.

**EDIT:**

This error you are reporting is because you need to inicialize your app module. Include this line of code in the beginning of your js

```
angular.module('myNgApp', []);
angular.module('myNgApp').directive('hpdTable', TableView);
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/nomod?p0=myNgApp(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:2005b @ angular.js:1929(anonymous function) @ angular.js:2003(anonymous function) @ TableView.js:1
angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myNgApp&p1=Error%3A…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)

Comment: This way??

angular.module('myNgApp', []).directive('hpdTable', TableView);

Comment: Edited again. I would do separate, just because, usually we inicialize the module in a different file from the directive.

Comment: Great. Now I am getting another error message: 

angular.js:10765 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/dev/la/tableView.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10765r @ angular.js:10558g @ angular.js:10268(anonymous function)